# Reading File In JAR using Relative Path

Tags: java, jar, getresource

I have some text configuration file that need to be read by my program.  My current code is:

```
protected File getConfigFile() {
    URL url = getClass().getResource("wof.txt");
    return new File(url.getFile().replaceAll("%20", " "));
}
```

This works when I run it locally in eclipse, though I did have to do that hack to deal with the space in the path name.  The config file is in the same package as the method above.  However, when I export the application as a jar I am having problems with it.  The jar exists on a shared, mapped network drive Z:.  When I run the application from command line I get this error:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\Z:\apps\jar\apps.jar!\vp\fsm\configs\wof.txt

How can I get this working?  I just want to tell java to read a file in the same directory as the current class.

Thanks,
Jonah

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When the file is inside a jar, you can't use the `File` class to represent it, since it is a `jar:` URI. Instead, the URL class itself already gives you with `openStream()` the possibility to read the contents.

Or you can shortcut this by using `getResourceAsStream()` instead of `getResource()`.

To get a BufferedReader (which is easier to use, as it has a `readLine()` method), use the usual stream-wrapping:

```
InputStream configStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("wof.txt");
BufferedReader configReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(configStream, "UTF-8"));
```

Instead of "UTF-8" use the encoding actually used by the file (i.e. which you used in the editor).

---

Another point: Even if you only have `file:` URIs, you should not do the URL to File-conversion yourself, instead use `new File(url.toURI())`. This works for other problematic characters as well.

Comment: Paulo, thanks.  The problem is I ultimately need to get a BufferedReader.  How can I do that if I use getResourceAsStream()?

Comment: new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("wof.txt")))