# java read file for ftp upload from jar file

Tags: java, ftp, fileinputstream

I am trying to upload files by ftp using the apache common library. I want to keep those file inside the jar, since these are files that will stay the same and need to be uploaded on the different hosts several time.

I am trying the following:

```
    public void doCGIRecovery() throws IOException{
    System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/cgi/example").getPath());
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(getClass().getResource("/cgi/example").getPath());
    f.storeFile("./", file);
}
```

Using eclipse this works and the sysout is giving me:

```
/Users/user/Documents/workspace/example-Project/bin/com/example/java/example/business/cgi/example
```

But after the compilation into a jar it returns me the following:

```
file:/Users/user/Desktop/example.jar!/com/example/java/example/business/cgi/example
```

And I get (No such file or directory).

So how does that come? Further where does the "!" after example.jar come from?

Best Regards

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054435/reading-file-in-jar-using-relative-path

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about messing with the path, use getClass().getResourceAsStream() instead.

Comment: I tried that too, but the problem is, getClass().getResourceAsStream() returns a inputstream, and I need a FileInputStream. And I cannot cast the InputStream to FileInputStream.

Comment: Then you may have a problem since items packaged in a .jar aren't individual files any more.  The standard File API can't access them directly.