# How to make a relative path to my file?

Tags: java, path

i use eclipse
and my structure looks like this:

```
TSG-jar
 ->src
   ->myBean.java  (here i need a path)
```

and another one web application

```
TSG-war
  ->WebContent
     ->js
       ->boot.js
```

so they are both in the same workspace

I call the boot.js file from TSG-war in my TSG-jar (from myBean.java), and i need a path...but i have no idea how to do it...

In myBean.java i got this code:

```
private String getSrc(String path) {
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        in.close();
        return sb.toString();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I need the path of the javaScript.js file to send it to the function...

can u help me?

i tried:

```
String s = "..\\..\\..\\TSG-war\\WebContent\\js\\boot.js"
String s = "\\..\\..\\..\\TSG-war\\WebContent\\js\\boot.js"
String s = "\\..\\..\\..\\..\\TSG-war\\WebContent\\js\\boot.js"


System.out.println(getSrc(s));
```

its always null...

where is the error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054435/reading-file-in-jar-using-relative-path

Comment: TSG-war is a web app, but what is TSG-jar?

Comment: its not the same, my file is not in the same package as the bean...not even in the same folder...

Comment: not even in the same project...

Comment: simple java application project

Comment: do u got any ideas?

Comment: you have to provide full path if its not a web application

Comment: How are the two project related (at run time?)

Comment: they r both in an EAR file...

Comment: yes, at runtime

Comment: You cannot assume that a file in a .war file is accessible from an EJB

Comment: so, it;s not possible?

Comment: Not directly. But I imagine that you're calling EJB methods from your webapp, so you can read the content of the file in a string and pass it to your EJB via a method.

Comment: i guess, i could give it a try...thx